# Масштабирование переменных в Modbas

Tags: c#, modbus

Столкнулся с проблемой маштабирования в Modbus tcp. Читаю данные на скаду. Контроллер Roc809, scada complicity 8.2. Проблема в следующем, знаю что на контроллере с читаемого регистра значение 320, а на скаду приходит вообще другое, какое-то нереально( хотел бы я столько нулей в швецарском банке). Когда читаю модбас сканером, проблема остается, но она решается нажатием на кнопку Swapped fp...как реализовать такую кнопочку в C# на скаде... заранее спасибо.кстати говоря читаю даблфлоут...

**P.S.**

Отправляет **PLC Roc 809**, принимает **Scada complicity 8.2**, протокол связи **Modbus TCP/IP**, в модбас карте контроллера считываемые регистры *start 1000 end 1002*, конверсия *70*(т.е. IEEE floating point, читается функциями 3,4, 16), скада-модбас мастер, регистр приема D1001, где D Holding Registers as Double Precision... значение постоянно прыгает, когда ставишь swapped fp, все показывает отлично, но это в modscan.
Контроллер отправляет значение 320, а скада принимает значение -1,#QNANO

Comment: Отправляет PLC Roc 809, принимает Scada cimplicity 8.2, протокол связи Modbus TCP/IP, в модбас карте контроллера считываемые регистры start 1000 end 1002, конверсия 70(т.е. IEEE floating point, читается функциями 3,4, 16), скада-модбас мастер, регистр приема D1001, где D Holding Registers as Double Precision... значение постоянно прыгает, когда ставишь swapped fp, все показывает отлично, но это в modscan..

Comment: Контроллер отправляет значение 320, а скада принимает значение -1,#QNANO

Comment: Регистр приема в скаде D41001

Comment: Точнее надо перевернуть данные...как-бы инверсию произвести...

Comment: эм.. Код? или проблемы со стороним ПО?

Comment: По сути кода никакого нет, просто настраивается порт, настройки порта произвел, до этого ваще ничего не читало... также все возможные варианты настроек порта проверил... значит проблемы со сторонним ПО.

Comment: Проблема прояснилась немного, некорректное отображение данных происходит из-за того, что порядок битов отправителя и получателя не совпадают... остается разбивать по битно и собирать биты как мне надо... может у кого-нибудь есть рабочий код для этой реализации? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установил ОРС сервер и все пошло как по маслу...